# How can I fix this error?

Tags: visualforce, pre-chat

> Error: Web_Chat line 9, column 2: The markup in the document following
> the root element must be well-formed   Error  Error: The markup in the
> document following the root element must be well-formed

```html
<apex:page>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>


<style type='text/css'>
    .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton {
        background-color: #565656;
        font-family: "Salesforce Sans", sans-serif;
    }
    .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton:focus {
        outline: 1px solid #565656;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Salesforce Sans';
        src: url('https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/etc/clientlibs/sfdc-aem-master/clientlibs_base/fonts/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/etc/clientlibs/sfdc-aem-master/clientlibs_base/fonts/SalesforceSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
        embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
        embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'

        //embedded_svc.settings.defaultMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Chat with an Expert)
        //embedded_svc.settings.disabledMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Agent Offline)

        //embedded_svc.settings.loadingText = ''; //(Defaults to Loading)
        //embedded_svc.settings.storageDomain = 'yourdomain.com'; //(Sets the domain for your deployment so that visitors can navigate subdomains during a chat session)

        // Settings for Chat
        //embedded_svc.settings.directToButtonRouting = function(prechatFormData) {
            // Dynamically changes the button ID based on what the visitor enters in the pre-chat form.
            // Returns a valid button ID.
        //};
        //embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields = {}; //Sets the auto-population of pre-chat form fields
        //embedded_svc.settings.fallbackRouting = []; //An array of button IDs, user IDs, or userId_buttonId
        //embedded_svc.settings.offlineSupportMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Contact Us)

        embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
        embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';

        embedded_svc.init(
            'https://empathetic-bear-vt56l9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://nigelscommunities-developer-edition.na150.force.com',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '00D4x000000JXBk',
            'Chat_Agents',
            {
                baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la3-c1-ia4.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                deploymentId: '5724x000000LLZT',
                buttonId: '5734x000000LLaa',
                baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la3-c1-ia4.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                eswLiveAgentDevName: 'Chat_Agents',
                isOfflineSupportEnabled: true
            }
        );
    };

    if (!window.embedded_svc) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://empathetic-bear-vt56l9-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
        s.onload = function() {
            initESW(null);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    } else {
        initESW('https://service.force.com');
    }
</script>


<apex:page>
  <h1>Let’s start chatting...</h1>
  <br />
  Click the button to start a chat.
  <br />
  <!--Embedded Service Snippet-->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your code must be inside `apex:page` tag, currently you have two `apex:page` tags.

Comment: Your `<style>` and `<script>` tag should also be inside `<apex:page>`